# How do I display all dates that has more than 3 absent and 3 lates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have here a SQL Query

```
SELECT
 student.`firstname` AS student_firstname,
 student.`lastname` AS student_lastname,
 DATE_FORMAT(attendance.`date`, '%M %d, %Y') AS attendance_date,
 class.`subcode` AS class_subcode,
 student.`idno` AS student_idno
FROM
 `student` student INNER JOIN `attendance` attendance ON student.`idno` = attendance.`sidno`
 INNER JOIN `class` class ON attendance.`classid` = class.`id`
WHERE
 class.iidno = 930

AND  attendance.time_in='00:00:00'

ORDER BY
 class.subcode,
 student.lastname, 
 attendance.date
ASC
```

It displays all the dates with the names of the student. Now I need to display only if the student has more than 3 `attendance.remark='absent'` in the record and more than 3 `attendance.remark='late'` in the record. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of query, you want an aggregation query, presumably with one row per student.  Then you can use conditional aggregation to calculate the number of absents and lates and use a `having` clause for filtering:

```
SELECT s.*,
       SUM(a.remark = 'absent') as absents,
       SUM(a.remark = 'late') as lates
FROM student s INNER JOIN 
     attendance a
     ON s.idno = a.sidno INNER JOIN 
     class c
     ON a.`classid` = c.`id`
WHERE c.iidno = 930 AND attendance.time_in='00:00:00'
GROUP BY s.idno
HAVING absents >= 3 and lates >= 3;
```

Comment: Thanks. There is still lacking though so I'm gonna ask a new question.